# Unity Particle System Управление скоростью воспроизвидения в runtime

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть анимация атаки, для персонажа "мага". К этой анимации присвоен эффект Particle. Я хочу, чтобы скорость воспроизведения эффекта был синхронизирован с скорость воспроизведения анимации. Скорость анимации я передаю в Particle. Но тут я сразу встречаю проблему. Мне нужно как-то редактировать скорость воспроизведения глобальную. Потому что в эффекте у меня есть другие 4 эффекта. У которых другая скорость. И присваивать всем одну скорость не думаю что правильно. Можно как-то управлять глобально скорость? Не влияя на speed?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Как еще детальнее возможно описать проблему? Как раз таки из-за передоза детали ничего и не понятно мне так кажется. Синхронизация анимации с эффектом. Все просто. Чем быстрее проигрывается анимация, тем быстрее проигрывается и эффект. Но нужно учитывать и их скорости!

Comment: Проблема в том что ты дергал `SimulationSpeed`, чего делать нельзя, потому, что она ровно для этих задач и предназначена. Проблему создал ты сам и ты это знаешь. Поменяй параметры, что бы `SimulationSpeed` был 1, или пиши скрипт который запомнить базовое значение `SimulationSpeed` и будет множить его на скорость.